# Two different ways of solving a combinatorics problem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, stirling-numbers

I am working on the following problem:

$ \bullet $ How many possibilities exist to assign $n$ people to $k$ rooms, when the rooms are different and there might be empty rooms.

**My attempt (version $1$).** The problem becomes quite easy when we look at it in the following way: we want to assign a room to each one of the $n$ people and each room might be assigned to $0,\dots,n$ people. With this in mind, denoting the set of people by $\{ P_1, \dots, P_n \}$, we have $k$ possibilites for each $P_i$ and then the answer comes given by $k^n.$

**My attempt (verson $2$ - using Stirling numbers).** Since the rooms are different, we know that the number $$ j! \, {n \brace j }$$
gives us the number of ways to assign $n$ people into $j$ different rooms. Furthermore, if some rooms might be empty, the number
$$ \binom{k}{j}j! \, {n \brace j}$$
gives us the number of ways to assign $n$ people into $j$ different rooms, which are picked from $k$ total rooms (this means that $k-j$ rooms are empty, here we just picked the rooms that must be non empty). Then, for example, the number of ways to assing $n$ people into $1$ room (of the total $k$ rooms) is given by
$$ \binom{k}{1} 1! \, {n \brace 1} $$
and so on. Then, this leads me to the conclusion that the answer we are looking for is
$$ \sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}j! \, {n \brace j}.  $$

**Concerns.** With further search, I found out the identity
$$ k^n = \sum_{j=0}^\color{red}{n} \binom{k}{j}j! \, {n \brace j} = \sum_{j=1}^\color{red}{n} \binom{k}{j}j! \, {n \brace j}$$
holds for every $k \in \mathbb R.$ **BUT** my answer isn't exactly this. With the two resolutions above, I have shown that
$$ k^n = \sum_{j=1}^\color{red}{k} \binom{k}{j}j! \, {n \brace j} $$
And I really can't see where I am messing this up $(?)$. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all very nicely thought through – you were only missing a tiny detail in the end. Both the binomial coefficient $\binom kj$ and the Stirling number $\left\{n\atop k\right\}$ are zero if the lower index is greater than the upper index. So the sum really only runs up to $\min(k,n)$ in either case.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Basically, if $n>k$, it follows that for every $j \in \{k+1,\dots,n\}$, $\binom{k}{j} = 0$ and so, $$ \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{k}{j}j! \, { n \brace j } = \sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}j! \, { n \brace j }  +\underbrace{ \sum_{j=k+1}^n  \binom{k}{j}j! \, { n \brace j }}_{=0} = \sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j}j! \, { n \brace j }.$$

Comment: On the other hand, if $k>n,$ it follows that for every $j \in \{n+1,\dots,k\}$, ${n \brace j} = 0$ and so, $$ \sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j} j! \, {n \brace j} = \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{k}{j} j! \, {n \brace j} + \underbrace{ \sum_{j=n+1}^k \binom{k}{j} j! \, {n \brace j} }_{=0} = \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{k}{j} j! \, {n \brace j}.$$ Is this correct? If so, the two claims are basically the same?

Comment: @Rodrigo: Yes, that's right.